# Accessing Hashmap but causing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

The goal of this program is to take an array put it into a hashmap. The key is the element in the array and the value is the amount of times the key is present in the array. I'm trying to remove all key value pairs such that if the frequency is greater than or equal to n. I'm getting a nullpointerexception on the server I'm running it on but I'm not getting it in my local machine. The line I indicated is where the code throws the exception on the server. It could be an edge case I'm missing. I'm not too sure.

```
//int data[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
//int n = 2;

public static int[] answer(int[] data, int n) {
  int[] output = new int[2];
  HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 
  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   if(map.containsKey(data[i])){
      map.put(data[i],map.get(data[i])+1);
   }else{
     map.put(data[i],1);
   }
 }

   int mapSize = map.size();
    for(int i=1;i<=mapSize;i++){
     if((int)map.get(i)>n){  //-----Null Pointer Exception occurs in this line
       map.remove(i);    
     }
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: 1. Using `<=` in a for loop condition is not safe, 2. removing from a collection while iterating without using an iterator is not safe. 3. If you run this through a debugger, you should *see* your problem face-to-face, why not do this?....

Comment: ^ As you iterate through the loop, the size of the map decreases and thus `mapSize` does not accurately reflect how many loops of the iteration you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through Map.Entry<> instead of for loop.

You map may not contain (i). map.get(i) in such case returns null which cannot be cast to primitive int. Hence, such exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried using Map.Entry and I got the error saying it's a restricted class. I'm assuming that means map is not allowed?

Comment: for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}

Comment: I just tried your method. I had it working before. This is the exact error I get when I use map: Use of restricted class java.util.Map$Entry

Comment: Can you post up the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if/get/put you can use merge and, as the other answers/comments point out - your are using wrong keys to access the map.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    counts.merge(data[i], 1, Integer::sum);
}

// and then filter it
Map<Integer, Integer> filtered = counts.entrySet().stream()
             .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() <= n)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: I’m getting three errors:
error: cannot find symbol
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
                      ^
error: invalid method reference
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

Comment: And the last one:                                                ^
  non-static method getValue() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Object declared in interface Entry
error: invalid method reference
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
                                          ^
  non-static method getKey() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where K is a type-variable:
    K extends Object declared in interface Entry

Comment: @kchopper compiles and runs fine with JDK 1.8